# crontab issue: executes every minute for an hour rather than once a day

Tags: cron

I have a crontab question:

```
0 6 * * * cd /path/to/file
```

which is supposed to execute every morning at 6:00

problem is, for some reason, it executes every minute for 60 minutes... strange.

what am I doing wrong? no other crontabs exist pointing to this file

I have researched this online and it would appeat this crontab notation is correct. thanks

Comment: Seems correctly written, did you reload your crontab after editing? I don't get why you'd run cd in crontab though?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using some strange editor that produce weird file endings or bad character encoding? Are you absolutely sure there's whitespaces everywhere it should? This is maybe trivial and needless to say, but I have encountered likewise problems where the solutions were of that kind. Check again :-)

Comment: just checked again, no white spacs

Comment: If it was a change from a previous crontab line: have you reloaded crontab? Or tried to restart the crontab daemon?